# PythonAnywhere wsgi deployment error

Tags: django, wsgi, pythonanywhere

I've followed the steps and everything works fine on a local server but when I try to deploy on PythonAnywhere I keep running into problems. I don't know what I'm doing with the WSGI file so I just copied and pasted a template with some adjustments:

```
import os
import sys

path = '/home/KTruong88/Kappa_Ranks/Kappa_Ranks/'
if path not in sys.path:
sys.path.append(path)

os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'Kappa_Ranks.settings'

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
application = get_wsgi_application
```

I try to run the thing, and it gives me in the error logs:

```
TypeError: get_wsgi_application() takes 0 positional arguments but 2 were given
```

I don't know how if I configured my wsgi file properly, and I don't know where I can even access the get_wsgi_application() function so I can adjust it, or if I could, what would I adjust it too. How can I fix this?

Comment: PA dev here. We have a page for tips in debugging common issues in the wsgi file here, if it helps:  [https://help.pythonanywhere.com/pages/DebuggingImportError](https://help.pythonanywhere.com/pages/DebuggingImportError).  otherwise drop us a line to support@pythonanywhere.com, we're happy to help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You did not need to "copy and paste" a WSGI file in the first place; it is included in the project that was created when you did `django-admin.py startproject`.

Nevertheless, the problem is that `application` should be the object returned from `get_wsgi_application`, not the function itself:

```
application = get_wsgi_application()
```

Comment: for info, pythonanywhere requires an additional wsgi file for configuration.  copy-pasting is quite a common way to make one.